# Make post request in redux-saga: problem with body of request

Tags: reactjs, http, redux, redux-saga

I would like to make post request in redux-saga. My code looks like:

```
const response = yield fetch('https://test.api/test', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    'auth[email]': 'test@test.test',
    'auth[password]': 'test'
  }),
});
```

How to rewrite body of request in redux-saga? In postman it works good. Problem in fields in array-style

Comment: is `/test` accept json payload, or is the usual x-www-form-urlencoded?

Comment: @Federkun in postman I put form-data param

Comment: then you don't need to pass the body as json; use FormData instead

Comment: @Federkun Can you show me please on my example? I don't use it before

Answer (score 4):

If you, on postman, are using `form-data` and it's working, then you should do the same when you call `fetch`.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('auth[email]', 'test@test.test');
formData.append('auth[password]', );

const response = yield fetch('https://test.api/test', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData
})
```